# Mimic tweet EventHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, event-handling

> I'm using react and want to mimic the EventHandler that is used on a twitter tweet (and many other things I'm sure).

## If the text of an element is highlighted and on mouse up fires, do nothing, but if it is just clicked without any text being highlighted, fire the event.

This is not the standard behavior of `onClick, onMouseUp, onMouseDown, or onMouseDownCapture`. I've also tried adding `onSelect={e => e.preventDefault}`.

I could measure the amount of time the mouse is down and if it's over x milliseconds do nothing, but I have a feeling there is an even simpler (or more correct) solution to this. Does anyone know?

```
<div
 className='post'
 onClick={() => {
          if(text is highlighted){
            do nothing;
          }
          else{
               do something;
          } 
}>
```

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I've included some pseudo-code, but there is really nothing more to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be helpful

> A Selection object represents the range of text selected by the user or the current position of the caret. To obtain a Selection object for examination or manipulation, call window.getSelection().[more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

```
 <div
      className="post"
      onClick={() => {
        if (window.getSelection().toString() !== "sample")
          console.log("Do somthings");
        else console.log("Do nothing");
      }}
    >
      sample
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. This is exactly what I needed. 
Here's what I ended up with:
`onClick={() =>
        window.getSelection().toString().length === 0 &&
        doSomething()
      }`
Works like a charm.